# What is the "~" at the end of some files on terminal?

Tags: command-line

When I look at my Desktop files on Terminal with the command `ls`, I see that some of my files have an extension like `~`.

I wonder what is the meaning of it. As an example:

```
Untitled Document 1~
```

Comment: take in account that these files will not be delete automatically after deleting the original file.

Answer (score 2):

Many editors use `file_name~` to save a temp copy of the original file.